# How to make a square relationship matrix

Tags: r

I want to make a square relationship matrix using gene expression data. My data subset is in this form:

```
gene.   Sample1     Sample2      Sample3     Sample4      Sample5
A      13.932431    5.366284     6.93992     6.818242     2.564284
B      21.111017    0.662061     1.563687    2.135377     0.261206
C      26.471751    0.932416     1.673144    1.606691     0.361993
D      27.597507   36.591138    28.371248   31.376842    30.893555
E      35.324703    0            1.462438    1.175831     0
F.      7.381737    3.083751     4.56243     6.64035      5.346179
G      20.689661   58.773005    29.078037   69.195561    58.661982
H       0           0            0           0            0
I       0           0            0           0            0
```

I want to use this formula: `X%*%X / ncol(X)`. I want to get a matrix with number of rows equal to number of columns which should be equal to the number of individuals. I have a total 500 samples and a total of 35,000 genes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't multiply `X` by `X`. Perhaps you want this?

Let's assume that the data you imported from your `.csv` file in a data.frame named `data`. You'll need to remove the character column that contains the gene symbols and then you can multiply the transpose of the matrix with itself.

```
mat <- as.matrix(data[,!names(data) %in% "gene"])
(t(mat) %*% mat) / nrow(mat)
         Sample1  Sample2  Sample3  Sample4  Sample5
Sample1 425.8389 262.4451 182.6579 285.6350 239.6188
Sample2 262.4451 536.9769 311.2274 586.1026 512.1032
Sample3 182.6579 311.2274 191.8691 331.9591 291.7184
Sample4 285.6350 586.1026 331.9591 652.4043 564.7350
Sample5 239.6188 512.1032 291.7184 564.7350 492.3329
```

**Sample Data**:

```
data <- structure(list(gene = structure(1:9, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"), class = "factor"), Sample1 = c(13.932431, 
21.111017, 26.471751, 27.597507, 35.324703, 7.381737, 20.689661, 
0, 0), Sample2 = c(5.366284, 0.662061, 0.932416, 36.591138, 0, 
3.083751, 58.773005, 0, 0), Sample3 = c(6.93992, 1.563687, 1.673144, 
28.371248, 1.462438, 4.56243, 29.078037, 0, 0), Sample4 = c(6.818242, 
2.135377, 1.606691, 31.376842, 1.175831, 6.64035, 69.195561, 
0, 0), Sample5 = c(2.564284, 0.261206, 0.361993, 30.893555, 0, 
5.346179, 58.661982, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is what I am looking for. But I have 500 samples and a total of 35,000 genes in total. Is there another way to input the data which takes less time to prepare the "data".

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear enough. I mean I have a big dataset. How can I make a "data" object after importing input csv file? Like you have mentioned individual labels, sample values for each sample in your answer for Sample Data. I think it will be time consuming to make such a dat object manually. Is there a way to automate it?